# Powershell initializing global to $null is failing

Tags: powershell, null

I am running a GUI that takes user input but can be changed before finalizing if they make a mistake.  When the form opens, I am trying to initialize the globals to null.  This is failing.  I put a breakpoint on the code and looked at the value before and then stepped into it.  The value does not change.

So for example, if I run the form and enter "Foo" as my global variable, exit the form, then run the form again, even after the line in question executes, the value of the global is still "Foo".  What is going on?  I have used this exact code with other GUIs and it never failed (but the values were generated automatically rather than based on user input).

```
# Define and initialize global variables
$global:ServerName = $null   # <-- This fails to reset the variable from the previous run of the form


function ValidateChoices(){
    $OKToGo = $true
    $TempServerName = $null
    try {
        # Only Allow Valid NETBios Name with AlphaNumberic and - up to 15 characters
        [ValidatePattern("^[A-Za-z\d-]{1,15}$")]$TempServerName = $ServerNameTextbox.Text
        $ServerNameTitle.BackColor = ""
        $ServerNameTextbox.BackColor = ""
        $global:ServerName = $TempServerName
    } catch {
        $OKToGo = $false
        $ServerNameTitle.BackColor = "Pink"
        $ServerNameTextbox.BackColor = "Pink"
    }

...

    if ( $OKToGo ){
        "ServerName=" + $global:ServerName | Out-File c:\debug.txt
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you close the PowerShell console/ISE between the two runs? "Global" *does* mean "global". Use the `script:` scope modifier if you want to a variable to live just in the scope of the script.

Comment: I did not close the console, but why would the assignment to $null outright fail?  I did a breakpoint analysis before and after the initialize line and the value stayed the same.

Comment: I've seen some strange behavior in PS 3.0 related to assigning to static fields. To work around the problem I used an expression like `(gv someVariable).value` instead of `$someVariable`. You could do something similar, both to debug what you're seeing (does `(gv -scope global servername).value` show same problem?), and as a potential workaround. FWIW, my theory (with no evidence though) is my problem is related to callsite caching in the DLR. You could also try to temporarily eliminate the ValidatePattern attribute. Finally u could see which runspace is active during the various assignments.

Comment: Here is the answer:

When ValidatePattern is run against a variable, those restrictions are kept and re-evaluated anytime an attempt to change the variable is made.  This holds true even if ValidatePattern was not explicitly called.  

And because it was a global variable, those restrictions rode through multiple iterations of the form.

Because $null does not conform to my listed ValidatePattern parameters, the call to change the value was ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: When ValidatePattern is run against a variable, those restrictions are kept and re-evaluated anytime an attempt to change the variable is made. This holds true even if ValidatePattern was not explicitly called. And because it was a global variable, those restrictions rode through multiple iterations of the form. Because $null does not conform to my listed ValidatePattern parameters, the call to change the value was ignored